# Is it possible to automatically render the texture on the back of a mesh as with WPF 3D Material.BackMaterial property?

Tags: wpf, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

With HelixToolkit.SharpDX.WPF when setting the material on a MeshGeometryModel3D, it does not seem possible to set a 'BackMaterial' on such that both the front and back of the mesh use the same material, in the particular usage case of applying textures with a DiffuseMap and DiffuseColor.

In WPF 3D this is possible by setting the BackMaterial property. Is there something similar I can access but I am not aware of?

Ideally I don't want to have to duplicate the model and reverse the winding order of the triangles to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following sample code:

```
        <hx:MeshGeometryModel3D
            CullMode="Front"
            FillMode="{Binding FillMode}"
            Geometry="{Binding Model}"
            InvertNormal="True"
            Material="{Binding InnerModelMaterial}" />
        <hx:MeshGeometryModel3D
            CullMode="Back"
            FillMode="{Binding FillMode}"
            Geometry="{Binding Model}"
            Material="{Binding ModelMaterial}" />
```